# How to remove a sub-list from a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I've got a big list of training_data with 50,000 samples. Every sample contains two sublists which contain two elements (sample, label).

I accidentally created another list inside the label item which has again two items.

i.e)

```
                              main_list

                           _______|_______
                          |               |
                       sample           label(list)
                                     _____|_____
                                a(list)        b(list)
```

I want to remove 'b' sub-list from every example (50000). I hope I did explain it correctly. Save me.

[image: As in the image, the output is one of the 50000 examples. And I want to remove the highlighted list from every example so that every example contains two items (the first complicated array and the list of 0s and 1s)]

Comment: whats wrong with running the line newlabel = label[0] and assinging the "a" list to a new variable?

Comment: If I understand correctly, try `new_list = [ [x[0], x[1][0]] for x in main_list]`. If I didn't understand correctly, read up on list comprehension and hopefully you'll be able to fix it...

Comment: @ItamarMushkin I believe itd be [[x[0], x[1][0] for x in main_list]

Comment: You're correct @Jkind9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, try `new_list = [ [x[0], x[1][0]] for x in main_list]`. In any way, list comprehension will probably be enough to fix your problem...

Comment: Thanks sir, you saved me. Thanks for taking out your time.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to recreate your list hierarchy as follows:

```py
a = ["w", "x"]
b = ["y", "z"]
label = [a, b]
sample = ["sample1", "sample2"]
main_list = [sample, label]
```

This gives us that

```py
print(main_list)
[['sample1', 'sample2'], [['w', 'x'], [ 'y', 'z']]]
```

Then to remove `b`, you simply have to set

```py
main_list = [main_list[0], main_list[1][0]]
```

Does this achieve what you want?

Comment: Thanks, sir. It helped. Though I had to use for loop like told in the above answer, thanks for taking out your time.